# Count how many months are represented in each year in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that have dates (`2011-03-12`). I managed to split it into two additional columns `year` and `month`. Here reduced example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2010, 1, 4], [2010, 1, 8], [2010, 2, 4], 
    [2011, 3, 8], [2010, 6, 16]],
    columns=['year', 'month', 'value'])
```

If I do:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month']).sum()
```

I can clearly see that year `2010` has three months, but only 1 for `2011`.

I could like to display how many months are represented each year.

```
year  months
2010       3
2011       1
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRy with `nunique`:

```
df = df.groupby('year').agg({'month': 'nunique'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
      month
year       
2010      3
2011      1
```

Comment: Also `df.groupby('year', as_index=False)['month'].nunique()` works